# G++ Compiling Error with .cpp

Tags: c++, g++

I am having issues with compiling my .cpp file. There is nothing wrong with the code, and I suck at C++ and g++, so sorry if I suck at this. Anyways, I am getting the error message:

```
'Main.cpp -o Main
error: Main.cpp: No such file or directory
g++: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.`
```

Any idea as to why this might be happening?

Comment: Maybe you're in the wrong directory.

Comment: Show the compilation command Also, are you sure `Main.cpp` is present in current working folder ?

Comment: I am sure it is in the current working folder.

Comment: If this is Linux, remember that file names are case sensitive, i.e., `Main.cpp` is not the same as `main.cpp` or even `mAiN.cPp`. You can have all three (and even more) for kicks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Say you have file `main.cpp` inside of directory `foo`. To compile it with GCC, you navigate to `foo` and issue this command:

```
g++ main.cpp
```

This has to work. There's not much more to it.

Comment: @user3233136: if the answer helped consider marking it as accepted, (the green tick under the voting arrows)

Comment: @Mhd.Tahawi That would help, I'm about to score 200 in a single day for the first time!

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Issuing this command won't generate any object file at all.

Comment: @faranwath, it sure does. For reasons lost in the mists of Unix prehistory, if you ask a compiler to write an executable, but don't give it a name, it is christened `a.out`.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, the `-o outputfile` flag can be given almost anywhere in the commandline (at least for GCC, it's been quite a while since I've had to wrangle with propietary compilers...).

Comment: @vonbrand Oh well, if you want to be _that_ exact, yes, the `a.out` is an object format. I only meant if won't give you an object file like `-c` does.

Comment: @vonbrand Yes! I've tried with my GCC 4.8.2 and the order didn't matter.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Actually, I've used GCC a lot from the command line and I'm pretty sure you can feed options and input files in any order you want, except for linking, of course. Order does matter there.

Comment: @faranwath Yes, I've also noticed this (as mentioned). S.th. undocumented or mysterious must go on in the OP's environment ;) ...

Answer (score 3):

The command

```
g++ -o Main Main.cpp
```

should create an executable named `Main` from your source files directly. The error message says that you either didn't specify any input files, or they can't be found in the current working directory (though I'd expect a message like `error: Cannot open 'Main.cpp'` then). Also be sure about the source filename spelling, when running the command from an OS supporting case sensitive filenames.

Saying

```
g++ Main.cpp
```

will create an executable file named `a.out` (which is the default name).

Answer (score -2):

I fixed it. Some times what happens is when you are using VS Code and say you were on your previous project and you open a new tab and start working there , and save in some other directory than your previous project , in the terminal below you are in the same directory and thats the reason this error comes.
Just open a new window ,save and check the terminal whether you are in correct directory and you are good to go !
Happy Coding !